# How do I determine when a distribution has reached a steady state?

Tags: distributions, stationarity, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a dataset of the properties of a population over time. The data come from a (sort-of) agent-based model, where agents reproduce (with evolution) and die. After some time, the population should reach a "steady state", where the agents have evolved to a survival strategy that is stable/self-sustaining over a long period of time. I would like to determine when the population has reached this point (has stopped changing or become stable over time). It's possible that there is more than one survival strategy, so there could be two different sub-populations with different values for the property, both of which are stable.

Even after this point, the distribution will change slightly as agents die and reproduce, so there should be some tolerance for variation in whatever test I use. But agents that are not well-adapted should die more quickly than agents that are optimal, so the distribution should not change too much once the optimal strategy (or strategies) has been reached.

I'm not interested in outliers especially - there will always be outliers with this sort of model, but they generally die very quickly. The mean and median are pretty meaningless (pun not intended) for this data, because there could be more than one strategy that is viable (i.e. two peaks in the density distribution). As noted above, the size of the population can change too, so the standard deviation is probably not a particularly useful metric either. Due to the sheer amount of data I have, I'm looking for a few numbers that I can put in a table rather than something like a QQ plot.

What's the correct test to use here? I'm looking for something like an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test only on a distribution, rather than a single point.

What I had come up with myself was to use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic between the distribution at time 0 and the distribution at time $n$ (call this $KS_0$), and between the distribution at time $n$ and at time $n - 1$ (call this $KS_{n-1}$). When the distribution is in a steady state, $KS_0$ should be stationary around some constant (the distribution will have moved away from the distribution at $t=0$, but is otherwise not changing) and $KS_{n-1}$ should be approximately stationary around 0 (the distribution has stopped changing between time steps). I could then even use a ADF test on the $KS_0$ and $KS_{n-1}$ timeseries to test the stationarity of those. This is probably somewhat crude, but I don't need to be especially rigorous.

I am a physicist, not a mathematician, so it's most likely a lack of terminology that has meant I am unable to find such a test by myself. Answers that I can implement in Python are preferred!

Comment: What you might mean by "steady state" looks inconsistent.  In the classroom example, presumably the children in a true steady state would have a distribution of ages appropriate for that classroom--which means they are all still growing.  There seems to be a confusion between the dynamics of the changing classroom and the temporal evolution of the individuals within it.  Please clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: Perhaps rather than class I mean a cohort of students, who all go to the same schools and university. Say we start tracking their heights once a month at age 4. After 20 years, they will mostly have stopped growing. The data that I have is a population that evolves over time and should eventually reach an optimal survival strategy, and I'd like to know when they've stopped evolving. I should have used a better example, you're right.

Comment: That is clear, but it is fundamentally different from a steady state!  I believe you might be searching for words like "asymptotic distribution." It would be a good idea to edit your post to reflect what you mean.

Comment: In the height example, even each individual has stopped evolving. Are you after that, or after a more general "steady state" where the [property] of each individual still varies over time, but this variation (and/or members entering and exiting the population) balance out so that the distribution is stationary?

Comment: There will still be some variation in the population, because the individuals reproduce with some randomness, and some individuals will die of old age. But they should have reached the optimum strategy, so any individuals that differ from the optimum will die off quickly, and the bulk of the organisms should be optimal-ish. Asymptotic distributions sound like they might be what I'm after - like I said, I probably just lack the terminology to describe what I want!

Comment: @JuhoKokkala - "the [property] of each individual still varies over time, but this variation (and/or members entering and exiting the population) balance out so that the distribution is stationary?" - exactly this

Comment: Is "steady state" intended to be for each property separately? Or for the entire suite of properties taken together? Also, are the properties continuous, categorical, or some combination?

Comment: It would be nice, but there's far too much data to look at all properties together. I am content to look at one at a time. All the properties are continuous but some are limited to a range (e.g. [0, 1]).